# Office 365 rules and alerts does have Run a script option

Tags: outlook

I have successfully been running an Outlook Rule which moves an email and executes a macro via the Run a Script Option.  My company has recently migrated our Outlook to Outlook 365, and since then, the "Run a Script" option does not appear when creating an Outlook rule.

Has anyone come across this before and know of a fix?

Comment: Found the solution on another website:

Comment: 1. Click Start -> Search, type ‘regedit’ (Note: there is no quotation marks in the command.) and press Enter.

2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security.

3. Right-click a blank area, create a new DWORD Value named as ‘EnableUnsafeClientMailRules’ and set it to 1.

Note: Please back up the Registry before performing the steps above. You can refer to  this article to back up your Registry.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/outlook-rules-option-for-macros-missing-after/aae32b30-a753-485d-b902-6de18d51a5f9

Answer (score 0):

This is from T Hess's comment above. Putting it here in case some people don't look at the comments.

1. Click Start -> Search, type ‘regedit’ (Note: there is no quotation marks in the command.) and press Enter.
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security.
3. Right-click a blank area, create a new DWORD Value named as ‘EnableUnsafeClientMailRules’ and set it to 1.

Note: Please back up the Registry before performing the steps above. You can refer to this article to back up your Registry: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/outlook-rules-option-for-macros-missing-after/aae32b30-a753-485d-b902-6de18d51a5f9